# LuaLaTeX cannot find C module, but Lua can

Tags: luatex, lua, modules

My directory looks like this:

```
main.so
mainlua.lua
maintex.tex
```

where `main.so` is a module written in C++.

---

`mainlua.lua` contains the following code:

```lua
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";./?.so;"

local math = require "main"

int, res = math.integral("-1/2*x^2+x+4", -2, 4)

print(int)
print(res)
```

and executing

```bash
lua mainlua.lua
```

correctly prints the two variables.

---

`maintex.tex` on the other hand contains pretty much the same code, namely

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}    
    package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";./?.so;"
    local math = require "main"

    int, res = math.integral("-1/2*x^2+x+4", -2, 4)
\end{luacode}

The integral $\directlua{tex.print(int)}$ is equal to $\directlua{tex.print(res)}$.

\end{document}
```

however, if I try to execute

```bash
lualatex maintex.tex --shell-escape
```

I get the following error:

```bash
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./maintex.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
 L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
(./maintex.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)[\direc
tlua]:2: module 'main' not found:
    no field package.preload['main']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'main'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:2: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }                                                  

l.12 \end{luacode}                 

?
```

---

I am using `Ubuntu 21.04` with `LuaLaTeX 1.12.0` from `TeX Live 2020` as well as `Lua 5.3.3`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

The `.so` file itself does not seem to be the problem, because when using the standalone `lua` it works, just not when using `lualatex`. So I think it has to be a problem with the paths, but I do not know what to change.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the issue, but using the name `math` is a very bad idea since it hides the Lua standard `math` library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one side remark: You are setting `package.cpath` which is needed in standalone Lua, but it's ignored in LuaTeX since there modules are found using TeX Live's kpathsea and not using Lua's regular `package.path/cpath` based system. That's not causing your issue though since kpathsea by default looks in the current directory, so the path is already set correctly.

So let's come to the real issue: You have to invoke LuaLaTeX with the `-shell-escape` option, otherwise modules written in native code can't be loaded for security reasons. (Without `-shell-escape` you are not allowed to run arbitrary programs which would be completely pointless if you could still load unrestricted native code)

Comment: Thank you... I ran `lualatex maintex.tex --shell-escape` which was wrong, I have to run `lualatex --shell-escape maintex.tex` instead. Stupid mistake :)